Substitute for QuantumInstance in latest qiskit==1.0
I have a old version of qiskit==0.46 code which uses the below syntax:
quantum_instance = QuantumInstance(backend= backend,
                                                shots= self.shots_done,   
                                                seed_simulator= 28,   
                                                seed_transpiler= 28,
                                                basis_gates= None,
                                                optimization_level=self.optimization_level_used)

This API no longer works in the latest version of qiskit==1.0.
Please suggest me a API which exactly do this function in the latest qiskit==1.0?
Edit1
Explaining the problem more clearly. Below is the complete code:
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
import numpy as np
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp
from qiskit.circuit.library import EfficientSU2
# from qiskit.utils import QuantumInstance # Need to replace it with something else
from qiskit_algorithms import VQE



 Hamiltonian = [
    [ 4.07981221, -3.6713615 ,  1.3943662 , -1.05164319],
    [-3.6713615 ,  5.88262911, -4.14084507,  1.37558685],
    [ 1.3943662 , -4.14084507,  5.83098592, -3.54929577],
    [-1.05164319,  1.37558685, -3.54929577,  3.79812207]
]
H_op = SparsePauliOp.from_operator(Hamiltonian)
ansatz = EfficientSU2(num_qubits=num_qubits,
                                entanglement= 'linear',
                                reps= depth,
                                skip_final_rotation_layer= True)
    
backend = AerSimulator()

ansatz_opt = transpile(circuits=ansatz,
                         backend = backend,
                          optimization_level =self.optimization_level_used)
            
optimizer = COBYLA(maxiter= 1500)
quantum_instance = QuantumInstance(backend= backend,
                                    shots= 1000,                                                   
                                   seed_simulator= 28,  
                                   seed_transpiler= 28,
                                   basis_gates= None,
                                   optimization_level=1)
    
           
           
initial_point_values = 2*np.pi*np.random.rand(ansatz_opt.num_parameters)
vqe = VQE(ansatz=ansatz_opt,
          optimizer= optimizer,
          quantum_instance=quantum_instance,
           initial_point=initial_point_values
          )

This code fails at QuantumInstance when I use the qiskit==1.0? Need some substitute for QuantumInstance?
Edit2
This code works on qiskit==0.46. Just to be sure I am not missing anything,the other qiskit related packages in my conda env are :
qiskit-aer==0.13.3 , qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.20.2, qiskit-terra==0.46.0
from qiskit import transpile
from qiskit import Aer
import numpy as np
from qiskit.opflow import MatrixOp
from qiskit.circuit.library import EfficientSU2
from qiskit.algorithms.optimizers import COBYLA

from qiskit.utils import QuantumInstance
from qiskit.algorithms import VQE
backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
Hamiltonian = [
    [ 4.07981221, -3.6713615 ,  1.3943662 , -1.05164319],
    [-3.6713615 ,  5.88262911, -4.14084507,  1.37558685],
    [ 1.3943662 , -4.14084507,  5.83098592, -3.54929577],
    [-1.05164319,  1.37558685, -3.54929577,  3.79812207]
]
H_op = MatrixOp(Hamiltonian).to_pauli_op()
ansatz = EfficientSU2(num_qubits=2,
                    entanglement= 'linear',
                    reps= 5,
                    skip_final_rotation_layer= True)
ansatz_opt = transpile(circuits=ansatz,
                            backend = backend,
                            optimization_level =3)
optimizer = COBYLA(maxiter= 1500)
quantum_instance = QuantumInstance(backend= backend,
                                        shots= 1024,     # default is 1024   # changing the number of shots to 32M
                                        seed_simulator= 28,    ##
                                        seed_transpiler= 28,
                                        basis_gates= None,
                                        optimization_level=2)

initial_point_values = 2*np.pi*np.random.rand(ansatz_opt.num_parameters)
vqe = VQE(ansatz=ansatz_opt,
        optimizer= optimizer,
        quantum_instance=quantum_instance,
        initial_point=initial_point_values
        )

result = vqe.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(H_op)
print(result)

(VQE_backup) m2c693@alveo:~/RESEARCH_WORK$ python TESTING_VQE_CODE.py 
: DeprecationWarning: The ``qiskit.opflow`` module is deprecated as of qiskit-terra 0.24.0. It will be removed in Qiskit 1.0. For code migration guidelines, visit https://qisk.it/opflow_migration.
  from qiskit.opflow import MatrixOp
/home/m2c693/RESEARCH_WORK/TESTING_VQE_CODE.py:10: DeprecationWarning: ``qiskit.algorithms`` has been migrated to an independent package: https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-algorithms. The ``qiskit.algorithms`` import path is deprecated as of qiskit-terra 0.25.0 and will be removed in Qiskit 1.0. Please run ``pip install qiskit_algorithms`` and use ``import qiskit_algorithms`` instead.
  from qiskit.algorithms.optimizers import COBYLA
/home/m2c693/RESEARCH_WORK/TESTING_VQE_CODE.py:14: DeprecationWarning: The 'qiskit.Aer' entry point is deprecated and will be removed in Qiskit 1.0. You should use 'qiskit_aer.Aer' directly instead.
  backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
/home/m2c693/RESEARCH_WORK/TESTING_VQE_CODE.py:21: DeprecationWarning: The class ``qiskit.opflow.primitive_ops.matrix_op.MatrixOp`` is deprecated as of qiskit-terra 0.24.0. It will be removed in the Qiskit 1.0 release. For code migration guidelines, visit https://qisk.it/opflow_migration.
  H_op = MatrixOp(Hamiltonian).to_pauli_op()
/home/m2c693/RESEARCH_WORK/TESTING_VQE_CODE.py:30: DeprecationWarning: The class ``qiskit.utils.quantum_instance.QuantumInstance`` is deprecated as of qiskit-terra 0.24.0. It will be removed in the Qiskit 1.0 release. For code migration guidelines, visit https://qisk.it/qi_migration.
  quantum_instance = QuantumInstance(backend= backend,
/home/m2c693/RESEARCH_WORK/TESTING_VQE_CODE.py:39: DeprecationWarning: The class ``qiskit.algorithms.minimum_eigen_solvers.vqe.VQE`` is deprecated as of qiskit-terra 0.24.0. It will be removed no earlier than 3 months after the release date. Instead, use the class ``qiskit.algorithms.minimum_eigensolvers.VQE``. See https://qisk.it/algo_migration for a migration guide.
  vqe = VQE(ansatz=ansatz_opt,
{   'aux_operator_eigenvalues': None,
    'cost_function_evals': 204,
    'eigenstate': {   '00': 0.44743190822738604,
                      '01': 0.46351240544347894,
                      '10': 0.5321683239352001,
                      '11': 0.5493248697264671},
    'eigenvalue': (0.4073778676855462+0j),
    'optimal_circuit': None,
    'optimal_parameters': {   ParameterVectorElement(θ[0]): 3.413149701335303,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[1]): 6.122673310049739,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[2]): 5.007510090575305,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[3]): 6.471417603085951,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[4]): 5.5825713635512635,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[5]): 3.612049649783617,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[6]): 1.1964266917131818,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[7]): 1.2636714562893496,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[8]): 2.7107242130163205,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[9]): 1.4162337151620497,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[10]): 3.4685412184905724,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[11]): 7.0531779235955145,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[12]): 4.759785290450675,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[13]): 7.005034463907616,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[14]): 3.0544374104242245,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[15]): 3.6712390616198993,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[16]): 0.8180247608411803,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[17]): 2.890632566254878,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[18]): 3.2114389132830734,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[19]): 1.1110070869050546},
    'optimal_point': array([3.4131497 , 6.12267331, 5.00751009, 6.4714176 , 5.58257136,
       3.61204965, 1.19642669, 1.26367146, 2.71072421, 1.41623372,
       3.46854122, 7.05317792, 4.75978529, 7.00503446, 3.05443741,
       3.67123906, 0.81802476, 2.89063257, 3.21143891, 1.11100709]),
    'optimal_value': 0.4073778676855462,
    'optimizer_evals': None,
    'optimizer_result': None,
    'optimizer_time': 4.511643648147583}


I strongly encourage you to read the Qiskit 1.0 migration guide, in which you can find most of the info you need to update your code.
I'll give you that the Aer and Algorithms docs are not very helpful for now though.

Your code with Qiskit 1.0 is supposed to use the Estimator primitive, to which you can then pass some of these options. Most of them will be passed to the pass manager though.
In the following, I'll let as a comment your previous code, to see which lines you have to replace
In order to transpile your circuit with the options you set in your post, you should use the pass manager:
# from qiskit import transpile
from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager

Aer is not a part of Qiskit anymore, you have to use qiskit-aer:
# from qiskit import Aer
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator

The opflow module has been largely superseded by the quantum_info one:
# from qiskit.opflow import MatrixOp
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp

The algorithms module doesn't exist anymore, you have to use the qiskit-algorithms package:
# from qiskit.algorithms.optimizers import COBYLA
# from qiskit.algorithms import VQE
from qiskit_algorithms import VQE
from qiskit_algorithms.optimizers import COBYLA

As mentioned earlier, the QuantumInstance is supposed to be replaced with an Estimator Now, there is a slight problem, in the fact that you want to use a seed. So clearly, you want to perform a simulation. You can't use the Estimator from qiskit-ibm-runtime for that: the Estimator is supposed to be backend-agnostic, and it doesn't make sense to talk about a seed for a real quantum computer.
So, we could either use the Estimator from qiskit, or the one from qiskit-aer. Let's say that we want to use the one from qiskit-aer, since it is designed to be as efficient as possible.
# from qiskit.utils import QuantumInstance
from qiskit_aer.primitives import Estimator

Let's stop briefly on this. The Estimator from Aer is a V1 primitive. So, preferably, we should instead use the V2 version (which isn't present in the docs, but definitely present in the code). That's especially true since Qiskit won't support V1 primitives anymore on 15 August 2024. But there's a slight problem: the VQE class from qiskit-algorithms only supports... V1 primitives. So, we're left with essentially three choices here:

Use the V1 primitive for now, and see whether this becomes a problem in the future;
Pray that the V2 support for VQE in qiskit-algorithms arrive soon (which should be the case);
Implement our own version of the VQE algorithm.

The latter isn't as hard as it seems, you can find plenty of tutorials online. But for the sake of not reinventing the wheel, I'll go for solution #1 here.
The backend should now be defined using the AerSimulator:
# backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
backend = AerSimulator()

Note however that this backend is only used when transpiling the ansatz. When using the Aer primitives, a new backend is defined using the options directly passed to the primitives. So, there isn't really a reason to define it if you only intend to perform a simulation. The only perk is that if you want to use a real quantum machine later on, then you won't have to change the lines concerning the transpilation when redefining your backend variable. But you'll have to pas it to an EstimatorV2 from qiskit-ibm-runtime. End of the digression.
The operator should use the SparsePauliOp class:
# H_op = MatrixOp(Hamiltonian).to_pauli_op()
H_op = SparsePauliOp.from_operator(Hamiltonian)

You should transpile using a pass manager. Note that this is where you will pass most of the options of QuantumInstance:
# ansatz_opt = transpile(circuits=ansatz,
#                             backend = backend,
#                             optimization_level =3)
pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(
    optimization_level=3,
    backend=backend,
    basis_gates=None,
    seed_transpiler=28
)
ansatz_opt = pm.run(ansatz)

Now, we replace the QuantumInstance with our Estimator
# quantum_instance = QuantumInstance(backend= backend,
#                                         shots= 1024,     # default is 1024   # changing the number of shots to 32M
#                                         seed_simulator= 28,    ##
#                                         seed_transpiler= 28,
#                                         basis_gates= None,
#                                         optimization_level=2)
estimator = Estimator(
    run_options = {"shots": 1024, "seed": 28},
)

Note that if we were to use the V2 version, we would have had to write:
estimator = EstimatorV2(
    options={
        "run_options": {"shots": 1024, "seed": 28}
    }
)

This is also where you can put backend options, using the backend_options keyword argument of EstimatorV1, in a simialr way: a dict where the key is the option name, and the value the option value. This configuration is then used to crate an AerSimulator backend internally.
All in all, adapting the code you provided yields:
from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager

from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator

import numpy as np

from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp
from qiskit.circuit.library import EfficientSU2

from qiskit_algorithms import VQE
from qiskit_algorithms.optimizers import COBYLA

from qiskit_aer.primitives import Estimator as Estimator

backend = AerSimulator()

Hamiltonian = [
    [ 4.07981221, -3.6713615 ,  1.3943662 , -1.05164319],
    [-3.6713615 ,  5.88262911, -4.14084507,  1.37558685],
    [ 1.3943662 , -4.14084507,  5.83098592, -3.54929577],
    [-1.05164319,  1.37558685, -3.54929577,  3.79812207]
]

H_op = SparsePauliOp.from_operator(Hamiltonian)

ansatz = EfficientSU2(num_qubits=2,
                    entanglement= 'linear',
                    reps= 5,
                    skip_final_rotation_layer= True)

pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(
    optimization_level=3,
    backend=backend,
    basis_gates=None,
    seed_transpiler=28
)
ansatz_opt = pm.run(ansatz)

optimizer = COBYLA(maxiter= 1500)

estimator = Estimator(
    run_options = {"shots": 1024, "seed": 28},
)

initial_point_values = 2*np.pi*np.random.rand(ansatz_opt.num_parameters)

vqe = VQE(
    estimator=estimator,
    ansatz=ansatz_opt,
    optimizer=optimizer,
    initial_point=initial_point_values
)

result = vqe.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(H_op)
print(result)
```


Thank you for the response @TristanNemoz. I have edited the question to make it more clear. This quantum_instance variable I have to put as argument in VQE API (from qiskit_algorithms import VQE)

@Manu I've adapted the code. However, it's hard to see whether that'll match your needs without a fully reproducible example, including running the algorithm. That's true for any question you could ask here: it's always easier if it's possible to test the code works as intended.

Thank you @TristanNemoz for the continous help.  I have put a reproducible example in the Edit2, but it needs qiskit==0.46.

@Manu I've edited the answer so that the code is functional, please have a look

Thank you @TristanNemoz for this great and kind help. Now my problem is resolved. Thank you.
